# Как мне найти в каком участке кода и файле происходит JS ошибка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]Есть [сайт](http://ruchnoe-razmeschenie.ru/), где вылазит JS ошибка. Как мне найти в каком участке кода и файле происходит JS ошибка?

Comment: Что надо сделать, чтобы на неё нарваться? Открываю страницу "Контакты". Вижу `RetiredVersion: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages`.

Comment: синтаксическая ошибка в выборке $() скорее всего. Может так правильнее `a[href="#"]`

Comment: Самый простой способ - открыт каталог, в котором лежат все файлы сайта и сделать по ним поиск этого селектора.